# How to get the state of Azure VM in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, azure-virtual-machine

Prometheus' [`ec2_sd_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#ec2_sd_config) supports label `__meta_ec2_instance_state` to get the state of the EC2 instance.

Is there a similar meta label or some alternative way to extract state of the virtual machine for [`azure_sd_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#azure_sd_config)?

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, lost this nuance( Thanks for explanation.